# internal compiler error: Segmentation fault in gcc . when sending variadic template to struct

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, c++11, variadic-templates

I'm trying to compile following code :

```
#include <iostream>

template<template <typename...> class Container,class... Args>
struct Container
{};

template<class T1,class T2>
struct Store
{};

int main()
{
    Container<Store,int,double> a;
}
//g++ -Wall -std=c++11 main.cpp
```

[ideone](https://ideone.com/dj753H)

I'm using gcc 4.8.1 and I get the following error :

```
internal compiler error: Segmentation fault
 struct Container
        ^
```

Why  gcc does not compile it? Is that code correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Compiling with Clang reveals the error:

```
main.cpp:4:8: error: declaration of 'Container' shadows template parameter
struct Container
```

if you rename the struct or the template paremeter, the code compiles in g++ as well, I don't know if the same name of them was accidental or deliberate.

---

Also, g++ 4.8.2 and 4.9 work fine and give a similar error as Clang.

Comment: But the real issue is still a bug in GCC. Thanks for clarifying the problem nevertheless.

Comment: @user2799037, the real issue is the bug in OP's code, but it does apparently reveal a bug in gcc which prevents proper error message generation.

Comment: @user2799037 yes, it is. But if it as accidental, the OP can both move on and file a bug report. (though the latter seems unnecessary as it works with g++ 4.9)

Comment: I tried compiling that in vs2013 . It compiles fine(without any warning)

Comment: It seems VS2013 accepts `template <typename T> struct T { };` – although it does not have much sense.